# Access Query - Relationship query with 1 to 3 relationship

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a Microsoft access query I'm trying to set up but have hit a snag. I'd describe this as a select query that has a relationship of 1:3.

I have two tables (A & B), table B has one field (a new part number) that I need to compare against three fields in table A (old/new part numbers). I want to do a select query so I can export as a CSV. In this case I need to match 2ABCD so I get a row with the updated price of $5.

The basic format I'm looking at is this.

From table B, I want to check if UPC4 matches UPC1, UPC2 or UPC3 in table A - matching for the value "2ABCD" in this example. Ideally I want to do this in one query. Thoughts?

***TABLE A***

| UPC1 | UPC2 | UPC3 | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD | 1ABCD | 2ABCD | $4 |

***TABLE B***

| UPC4 | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 2ABCD | $5 |

***END RESULT SELECT QUERY***

| UPC1 | UPC2 | UPC3 | UPC4 | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD | 1ABCD | 2ABCD | 2ABCD | $5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access supports joins https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/access/concepts/structured-query-language/perform-joins-using-access-sql

So you can combine both tables

```
SELECT
    TableA.UPC1,TableA.UPC2,TableA.UPC3,
    TableB.UPC4,TableB.Price
FROM
    TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.UPC1 = TableB.UPC4
OR TableA.UPC2 = TableB.UPC4
OR TableA.UPC3 = TableB.UPC4
```

Comment: This did it! One follow up question occurs to me, what if tableA.UPC3 had leading zeros. I know I can do an LTrim replace but how could I get that to work in this context?

Comment: you would Replace() the zero with ''

Comment: `REPLACE(TableA.UPC3,'0','') =  TableB.UPC4`